# How can i add different images to combobox itemssource array

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I would like to add different images next to each item in a combobox itemssource. Here's what i have at the moment.

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cmb" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="135" Height="22"
          SelectedItem="{Binding myViewMode}" Margin="5,0,0,0">
          <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
               <x:Array Type="sys:String" xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">                                                                
                  <sys:String>Oranges</sys:String>
                  <sys:String>Mangoes</sys:String>
               </x:Array>
          </ComboBox.ItemsSource>                                                        
</ComboBox>
```

How should add the two diffent images using an itemtemplate. Thanks

## Edit One

This is what i have tried with itemtemplate

```
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
               <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Source="{Binding OrangesImage}" Height="100"/> 
<Image Source="{Binding MangoesImage}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
```

It's here that am really stuck.

Comment: Apparently you already know the answer: use of an item template. What have you tried so far?

Comment: When i use the itemtemplate it displays images without text

Comment: You have this tag [tag:mvvm] on your question, yet you appear to not know what it means.  I'd suggest taking a break from coding in order to learn it.  Shouldn't take more than a couple hours.  Lots of links out there.  Visit your favorite search engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment your item template contains only two images, so you will show two images and no text for each item!

I would suggest you change your ItemsSource to code behind so you can have text and image properties.

First make a simple Fruit class:

```
public class Fruit
{
    public string FruitName { get; set; }
    public string FruitImage { get; set; }
}
```

Then create a list of these fruits and set the ItemsSource of your combo box to this list:

```
var fruits = new List<Fruit>();

fruits.Add(new Fruit() { FruitName = "Mangos", FruitImage = @"C:\mangoimage.jpg" });
fruits.Add(new Fruit() { FruitName = "Oranges", FruitImage = @"C:\mangoimage.jpg" });

cmb.ItemsSource = fruits;
```

Then simplify your XAML thus:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cmb" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="135" Height="22" SelectedItem="{Binding myViewMode}" Margin="5,0,0,0">    
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding FruitName}"/>
                <Image Source="{Binding FruitImage}" Height="100"/>                        
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your ItemSource your image should consists as Uri path with BitMapImage Class then only Images are accepted in ItemTemplate in ComboBox

Xaml Code

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cmb" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="135" Height="22"
      SelectedItem="{Binding myViewMode}" Margin="5,0,0,0">
   <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Width="25" Height="25" Source="{Binding FruitName}"/>              
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
   </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
 </ComboBox>
```

Your Model Class

```
public class Fruit
{
public string FruitName { get; set; }   
}
```

Your ItemSource should Consists as:

```
fruitCollection.Add(new Fruit() {FruitName= new BitmapImage(new Uri("C:\mangoimage.jpg", UriKind.Relative))});
```